# How to structure a knockoutJS Jquery App

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, structure, knockout.js

**updated

I'm using the knockoutjs with jquery to build an application.

Because I'm using jquery, i have to wrap knockout in the jquery function. This is fine except that through the application i re-use the same objects/function for various different pages. Because the object contains references to knockout i can't put them in a global file meaning that i have a lot of repetition, seriously bloating my code and making it quite unmanageable.

So

```
//global file

//this is fine because it dose not reference knockout 
var global_cust = function(){
   this.name: "dave";
   this.isAwkward: true; 
}

//this is not fine because it references knockout 
var knockout_global_customer = function(properties){
  this.name: ko.observable(properties.name? properties.name: "unknown"),
  this.isAwkward: ko.observable(properties.isAwkward? properties.isAwkward: true),   
}

//page 1 

(function($){

//i have to include the customer in every page of aplplication that uses it. I would like this in a global file or someway of Precompiling it so don't have to include it in every page - a bit like php include but for JS    
var customer = function(properties){
  this.name: ko.observable(properties.name? properties.name: "unknown"),
  this.isAwkward: ko.observable(properties.isAwkward? properties.isAwkward: true),   
}

var viewModel = {
  currentCustomer: ko.observable(new customer()),
  globalCustomer: ko.observable(new global_cust()),
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

})(jQuery);
```

so is there anyway, or tools that pre process the files so that i don't have to keep replicating the same objects/functions on every page

Thanks

Comment: Why do You need access to viewmodel outside of world?

Comment: thanks for your comment, not sure what you mean by world, but it isn't the viewModel that i need to be global it's the customer function that the view model references. For each page of my app i have a different viewmodel that contains different properties, some of which reference objects /function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **window** variable for this purpose.

```
window.customerModel = viewModel;
```

it will be available globally.

Answer (score 0):

I like the window variable answer and think it fits you best. But for a "php include"-like function, check out the `jQuery.getScript` function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Wouldn't js be bloated with multiple repeated code after page load?

Comment: Like I said, I don't think this is the best solution for him, but it's relevant to his include question. I even upvoted the other guy. ;)